# Sampling from texture in fragment shader with UV's proportional to perspective

Tags: opengl, glsl

In the fragment shader:

If I have a texture (the size of viewport) uploaded as a uniform sampler2D.
The texture was rendered to in a earlier pass.
The currently running fragment corresponds 1:1 to the texture in UV space.
The fragment shader samples surrounding pixels in the texture based on a *delta* value.

**How can I keep *delta* proportional to the camera perspective?**

For instance: *delta* is 1 unit in world space.

If it helps, you can assume:

Camera has orthographic projection.

You have access to the fragments' world position.

viewport / texture - resolution: (1280, 720)

**Edit**

Here is what I think I could do:

Every frame on the CPU (or when the camera projection changes):

(sudo code)

Mat4 combined = camera.projection() * camera.view();

Vec4 world_delta = Vec4(1,1,0,0); // Not a position

Vec2 ndc_delta = (combined * world_delta).xy;

Vec2 uv_delta = ndc_delta / 2;

shader.uploadUniform(uv_delta);

Comment: Assuming an orthographic projection, and that delta is a 2d offset on the image plane: delta should be a constant which only depends on the projection matrix. The camera position or the fragment location shouldn't influence it.

Comment: Also, the texture resolution shouldn't be needed, only the scaling from world space to NDC is needed

Comment: @BDL Hi. Thanks for commenting. I had a suspicion the view matrix wouldn't matter. But even if we include it, would it have any effect on the "ndc_delta" anyway? Yes, the plane i draw to is parallel with the camera near/far-planes. If that was what you meant with: "delta is a 2d offset on the image plane". So then, if i calculate the "ndc_delta" (from the orthographic projection matrix only) i would get the world unit in ndc?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you really want an offset in the image plane or if you were talking about a world-space offset direction (like when blurring along the movement path of a particle). The problem with including the view matrix is that you are actually only interested in the scaling component of the matrix, but not in the rotation. If my assumption about what you want to achieve is correct, the ndc_delta should be something like `[1 / (right - left), 1 / (top - bottom)]`.

Comment: I suspect i have been overthinking :) . I think you are right. I will have to come back to to this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I was complicating the problem. Not understanding orthographic projection.

**How can I keep *delta* proportional to the camera perspective?**

A viewport [16,9] units and world_delta [1,1] units

```
width *= zoom;
height *= zoom;

right = width / 2;
left = -right
top = height / 2;
bottom = -top;
```

Then as BDL pointed out in the comments, you can derive the delta in NDC from:

```
ndc_delta.x = world_delta.x / (right - left);
ndc_delta.y = world_delta.y / (top - bottom);
```

or simply:

```
ndc_delta.x = world_delta.x / width;
ndc_delta.y = world_delta.y / height;
```